# how to hook up spring mvc to a dynamic list of data

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

So, i'm new to spring and I'm following this tutorial on spring mvc: http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/spring4_tutorial/mvc_web_application

That shows you how to create a website using spring mvc and display a list of cars. I have this working but I want to extend it so that the website isn't displaying a static list of cars.

Instead, I want the CarService to be more of a structure that can be updated dynamically so cars can be added and deleted. I have the CarService defined as a bean and I would like to just grab it when the controller asks for it.  The issue i'm running into, is how do I startup the web server and start my spring application that will start up the CarService so that we can add and remove separately from the web app?

Any guidance/tutorials on the best way to approach this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the tutorial, data (cars) is hardcoded in CarService for simplify.

If you want add cars dynamically (or all basic operations for data: CRUD - create, read, update, delete) and display them, you should:

1. Implement class DAO (Data Access Object) for cars, instead CarService with hardcored data.
2. Create forms for add cars (or for all CRUD) in yours JSP views.

Ad 1. You can store data in database (eg. MySQL, PostgreSQL) or file (eg. XML, binary) or Web Service (SOAP or REST). If you use database you can JDBC (with SQL query for add and retrieve data from database) or Hibernate (it's ORM - Object-Relational Mapping, automatically create objects).

You can use tutorial eg.:

- CRUD for Spring with Hibernate like this: http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial
- CRUD for Spring with JDBC like this: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-jdbctemplate-example

Comment: you are a noble soul.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple option

- You can use normal jdbc
- You Can use spring-orm tool
- You can use hibernate

All needs a database table e.g. mysql. and a bit more googling